# How can I create a word counting script using ONLY PHP and form using HTML?

Tags: php, html

```
I have the code but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.
```

I don't know what the this.php is for.
here is the instruction:
Create a form with one input that accepts text.
Once the user submits the form, their original input should be shown in the input field and the number of words in their input should be shown below the form.
Display an error message if the user submits no input.
As a bonus, also display the number of characters in the input below the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <h1>Word Counter</h1>
    <form action="this.php" method="post" class="form">
        <textarea name="input" class="form-control" style="width:50%">
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['input'])){
    echo $_POST['input'];
} 
?>
        </textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Count!" />
    </form>
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST['input'])){
        echo "<p><strong>Output:</strong><br>Number of Words: $words<br>Number of Characters: $chars</p>";
    } 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You submit the form to `this.php`, the URL that processes the form submission

Comment: SO where do you calculate `$words` looks like you just invented a variable

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If you want to do the PHP stuff on the same page instead of `this.php` remove `action="this.php"` from your `<form>`